# ag-grid column not automatically resizing in angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to fix the sizing of the columns issue on the ag-grid in angular 7 application. I have been trying several options as suggested but not getting a solution. What I am looking for is that the columns should automatically resize and take the width of the screen. At the moment
when it is rendering for the first time, the last column gets slightly hidden. The second problem that I have is when I reload the grid with data while navigating from another component to this page, the grid width change drastically.

I have tried to  add resize attribute on every column as well and also set the suppressSizeToFit: false with min-width and maxWidth defined.

Initial load

[image]

Reload of the grid while navigating from another component

[image]

html

```html
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="panel panel-default col-md-12">
        <div *ngIf="AllocationDetails && AllocationDetails.ManagerAllocations" class="panel-body">
          <div [style.height.px]="GridHeight()" [style.width.%]="100" style="float: left;">
            <span style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;padding-right: 10px;"><a (click)="expandAll()">Expand
                All</a></span>
            <span style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;"><a (click)="collapseAll()">Collapse
                All</a></span>
            <ag-grid-angular #agGrid class="ag-theme-balham" [gridOptions]="GridOptions" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
              [columnDefs]="ColumnDefs" [rowData]="AllocationDetails.ManagerAllocations" rowHeight="30" headerHeight="30"
              rowSelection="single" [pinnedBottomRowData]="pinnedBottomRowData"
              [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents">
            </ag-grid-angular>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

component

```js
    export class AllocationsComponent implements OnInit {


      constructor(private allocationsService: AllocationsService, private comparator: Comparator,
            private zone: NgZone, private route: ActivatedRoute, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {
            this.Comparator = comparator;
            this.Route = route;

            window.onresize = (e) => {
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight - this.offset;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        if (!this.GridOptions || !this.GridOptions.api) {
                            return;
                        }
                        this.GridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                    }, 500, true);
                });
            };
        }


        setGridOptions() {
            this.GridOptions = {
                columnDefs: this.getColumns(),
                enableFilter: true,
                treeData: true,
                enableColResize: true,
                animateRows: true,
                groupDefaultExpanded: 1,
                enableSorting: true,
                suppressAggFuncInHeader: false,

                getDataPath: function (data) {
                    return data.Hierarchy;
                },
                onGridReady: e => {
                    if (!e || !e.api) {
                        return;
                    }
                    e.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                    this.setDefaultSortOrder();
                },
                getRowStyle: (params) => {
                    if (params.node.level === 0) {
                        return { 'background-color': '#FCE7D7' };
                    } else if (params.node.level === 1) {
                        return { 'background-color': '#f4f4f4' };
                    }
                },

                autoGroupColumnDef: {
                    headerName: 'Manager Strategy', width: 300,
                    valueFormatter: uniqueColumn
                },

            };
            function uniqueColumn(params) {
                if (params && params.value != null) {
                const startIndex = params.value.indexOf('#');

                if (startIndex === -1) { return params.value; }

                const endIndex = params.value.length;
                return params.value.replace(params.value.substring(startIndex, endIndex), '');
                }

            }
        }

    ngOnInit() {

            this.evalDate = new Date();
            this.setGridOptions();
            this.getAllocationsDetails(this.FormattedDate(this.evalDate));


        }

         GridHeight() {
            if (!this.windowHeight) {
                this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight - this.offset + 10;
            }
            return this.windowHeight;
        }

         private getColumns(): Array<any> {
            const self = this;
            const columnDefs = new Array<any>();
            // const definition = [
                columnDefs.push({ headerName: 'Date', field: 'EvalDate', hide: true});
            columnDefs.push({ headerName: 'Firm ID', field: 'FirmID', hide: true });
            columnDefs.push({ headerName: 'Manager Strategy ID', field: 'FirmName', hide: true });
            columnDefs.push({ headerName: 'Firm', field: 'ManagerStrategyID', hide: true });
            columnDefs.push({ headerName: 'Manager Strategy', field: 'ManagerStrategyName', hide: true });
            columnDefs.push({ headerName: 'Fund ID', field: 'ManagerFundID', hide: true });
            columnDefs.push({ headerName: 'Fund', field: 'ManagerFundName', hide: true });
            columnDefs.push({ headerName: 'Product Name', field: 'ProductName', hide: true });
            columnDefs.push({
                headerName: 'As Of', field: 'EvalDate',
                cellStyle: { textAlign: 'right' },
                hide: false
                ,  width: 150, minWidth: 200, maxWidth: 300, suppressSizeToFit: false
            });
            columnDefs.push({
                headerName: 'EMV (USD)', field: 'UsdEmv', valueFormatter: this.currencyFormatter, rowGroup: false,
                cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
                aggFunc: 'sum',
                cellStyle: { textAlign: 'right' },
                pinnedRowCellRenderer: "customPinnedRowRenderer", pinnedRowCellRendererParams: { style: { "font-weight": "bold" }}
                ,  resizable :true
            });
            columnDefs.push({
                headerName: '% of Fund Strategy', field: 'GroupPercent', valueFormatter: this.formatPercent, rowGroup: false,
                cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
                aggFunc: 'sum',
                cellStyle: { textAlign: 'right' },
                pinnedRowCellRenderer: "customPinnedRowRenderer", pinnedRowCellRendererParams: { style: { "font-weight": "bold" } }
                ,  width: 150, minWidth: 200, maxWidth: 300, suppressSizeToFit: false
            });
            columnDefs.push({
                headerName: '% of Product', field: 'WeightWithEq',
                valueFormatter: this.formatPercent,
                cellStyle: { textAlign: 'right' }
                ,  width: 150, minWidth: 200, maxWidth: 300, suppressSizeToFit: false
            });



        this.pinnedBottomRowData = this.createData();
        this.frameworkComponents = { customPinnedRowRenderer: CustomPinnedRowRenderer };

        return columnDefs;
    }

    }
```

Comment: What version of Ag-Grid are you using?

Comment: The latest - ag-grid community

Comment: Have you tried the `ag-grid-angular` event binding `(gridSizeChanged)="onGridSizeChanged($event)"`?

Comment: No. Haven't. Can you tell me how to use it to fix my issue

Comment: Look at this example on their website `https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-responsiveness/#dynamic-resizing-without-horizontal-scroll`. Essentially you create the method back in the TS and call the sizeColumnsToFit() on the gridOptions api.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I just tried the example. I am not sure why my hidden columns are also seen

Comment: Sounds like you would need to reference the column updates prior to sizing the columns to fit then. Alternatively, try adding `onGridSizeChanged: () => this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit(),` on you `setGridOptions()` instead of the previous method I proposed. You can put this below the `onGridReady` entry.

Comment: You meant remove from the (gridSizeChanged)="onGridSizeChanged($event) from the grid right ?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, its much better but not consistent. I have a tab to toggle between the other and grid page. After three for toggles the column resizing gets disrupted

Comment: If you notice I am currently calling sizeColumnsToFit from four places on the page

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the event binding (gridSizeChanged) and see what happens if you remove the size ColumnsToFit() from within onGridReady.

Comment: I actually had tried that as well

Comment: Can you recreate using Stackblitz.com? The community might be able to assist better.

Comment: Could you explain what does this line mean  onGridSizeChanged: () => this.GridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit(),. I tried putting the breakpoint in the event but it never gets hit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191163/discussion-between-andrew-lobban-and-tom).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do,

On your HTML,

```html
<div id="div_grid">
  <ag-grid-angular #grid ...bunch of code here...
                   [enableColResize]="true"
                   (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"></ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

On your TS,

```js
private gridApi: GridApi;
constuctor(
  // bunch of code
  private elem: ElementRef,
){
  // bunch of code
}

onGridReady(params) {
    // bunch of code
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.sizeColumnsToFit();
}

sizeColumnsToFit() {
    const container = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('#div_grid');
    if (container[0] && container[0].clientWidth > this.gridWidth && this.gridApi) {
      this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
}
```

Assign value to `this.gridWidth` your total columns width when you work with columnsdefs.

Enjoy!!

Comment: @un.spike well this is how I use in my component. Please reason out.

Comment: `sizeColumnsToFit` should be executed after data binding.

Comment: will throw this error gridPanel.js:814 ag-Grid: tried to call sizeColumnsToFit() but the grid is coming back with zero width, maybe the grid is not visible yet on the screen? it should wait for first data to render ?